# Finding $\Re$ and $\Im$ of $e^{z^2}$

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers

I need to find $\Re f(z)$ and $\Im f(z)$ of $\color{blue}{f(z)=e^{z^2}}$

**My attempt:**

$$f(z)=e^{(x+yi)^2}=e^{x^2+2xyi-y^2}=e^{x^2}e^{2xyi}e^{-y^2}$$

Now what?

Comment: Now $e^{2xyi}=\cos(2xy)+i\sin(2xy)$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now

$$e^{2xyi}=\cos(2xy)+i\sin(2xy)$$

$$\Longrightarrow =\underbrace{e^{x^2}\cos(2xy)e^{-y^2}}_{=\Re}+i\underbrace{\sin(2xy)}_{\Im}$$